# Не работает input внутри цикла, когда делаю его параметром

Tags: python, циклы, input

Код выдает неправильный ответ, из-за того что input сделала переменной внутри цикла.

Как можно его исправить?
Обязательное условие, чтобы input был параметром, но так тоже не работает.

```
from collections import Counter


def score_sum(value=2, const="."):
    press = input()
    return sum(
        key <= value * int(press) for key in Counter(
            int(key) for _ in range(4) for key in press if key != const).values())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(score_sum())
```

Входные данные:

```
Ввод:  
3  
1231  
2..2  
2..2  
2..2  

Вывод:  
2
```

```
Ввод:  
4  
1111  
9999  
1111  
9911  

Вывод:  
1
```

Comment: Вы не сделали его "переменной внутри цикла", вы сделали его переменной, которая перед циклом получает значение единственный раз. И что значит "imput был параметром"?

Comment: пыталась сделать так ```def score_sum(, press=input,value=2, const="."): ```
так как требуется чтобы функция была универсальной и получала все данные через параметр

Comment: Попробуйте просто в теле функции вместо int(press)  написать int(input())

Comment: Ну так `def score_sum(press, value=2, const="."):`. А при вызове `print(score_sum(input()))`.

Comment: Немного не по теме но попробуйте написать код нормально, а не пихать все в одну строку. Станет гораздо легче работать и отлавливать ошибки. А то сейчас конечно имхо но пример как делать не надо.

Comment: @Kers я делаю так, как просит ревьюрер.. Инпуты так и не получилось сделать в параметрах. Не понимаю как исправить чтобы работало. Сейчас код выглядит так:

from collections import Counter


```def score_sum(press, type, value=2, const="."):
    return sum(
        key <= value * press for key in Counter(
            int(key) for _ in range(4)
            for key in type if key != const).values())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(score_sum(
        press=int(input()), type=input() + input() + input() + input()))```

Comment: Ох уж эти горе ревьюреры... Опишите что хотя-бы Ваш код должен рассчитывать? Постараюсь что-нибудь набросать.

Comment: Гоша и Тимофей нашли необычный тренажёр для скоростной печати и хотят освоить его.Тренажёр представляет собой поле из клавиш 4× 4,в котором на каждом раунде появляется конфигурация цифр и точек.На клавише написана либо точка,либо цифра от 1 до 9. В момент времени t игрок должен одновременно нажать на все клавиши, на которых написана цифра t. Гоша и Тимофей могут нажать в один момент времени на k клавиш каждый. Если в момент времени t были нажаты все нужные клавиши, то игроки получают 1 балл.
Найдите число баллов, которое смогут заработать Гоша и Тимофей, если будут нажимать на клавиши вдвоём.

Comment: узнала что внутри класса Counter input() из параметра функции не работает. Теперь главный вопрос, почему?